# Where can I locate org.wso2.carbon.mit.OpenIDClientImpl?

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I want to extend my key manager interface in wso2 api manager to connect it to a 3rd party azure interface. Any articles for this will be of great help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks to me like your question title and question body don't really match. Please try to edit your title to be closer to what you want help with. Also please consider providing code snippets and/or documentation links that show what you are actually doing, and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the source code in [1] and the article [2] which describes how to connect to Mitre ID Connect.

1. - https://github.com/jaadds/mitre-connect-demo
2. - https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/integrating-api-manager-with-mitre-id-connect/